# Infinitive verbs

Tags: infinitives

Please indicate the verb in this sentence'' I can swim in the river'' Here swim is an infinitive,so where is the main verb. Because infinitive can't be used as a verb.

Comment: Swim is not an infinitive there.  Swim _is_ the verb.  If it were an infinitive, the sentence would read something like "I like to swim in the river".

Comment: @RoyC. care to reconsider your definition of an infinitive in light of John Lawler's answer below?

Comment: From what I have read, an infinitive is usually to + verb.  After reading his answer, I'm still unsure.

Comment: @Roy C Look up 'bare infinitive' (or 'base form of a verb') and 'to-infinitive' to investigate the differences. Note that when looking at which of these may follow different verbs, 'help' proves to be rather odd in that it can take either: He helped wash the dishes / He helped to wash the dishes.

Comment: You are right: the 'main' ('matrix') verb is "can". _I can swim in the river_, is syntactically a present tense clause with "can" as the tensed verb. Thus "can" (not "swim") is the matrix verb with the non-finite clause "swim in the river" as a catenative complement.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously you have been told many semi-truths. Like the idea that there can be only one verb in sentence. There does have to be a verb somewhere, but there is often more than one verb in a verb phrase.

As for infinitives, don't confuse the form of the verb (the infinitive, or present, or basic, form of the verb -- in this case, *swim*) from the construction the verb form is in. This particular infinitive form of *swim* is obligatory because it is the verb following *can*, a modal auxiliary verb, and all modal auxiliary verbs must be followed by the infinitive form of the next verb in the verb phrase.

Since it is the last verb in the verb chain that is the matrix verb (what you might call the "main verb"), and since the form is determined by the preceding auxiliary verbs, if any, the main verb can have any of the following forms:

- present tense form:  *He sings the song.*
- past tense form: *He sang the song.*
- perfect participle form:  *He has sung the song.*
- present participle form:  *He is singing the song.*

(or, if the infinitive form is different from the present tense form, as it is with *be*

- infinitive  *He could be the singer.*)

All of these may be the matrix verb. There may be up to four auxiliary verbs coming before the matrix verb, in what is called the [Verb Chain](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), but it's the matrix verb that determines the meaning and grammar of the rest of the clause. As I used to tell my students, verbs have more fun.

Comment: I always thought an infinitive would be something like "to sing" as in " He wants to sing".  I'm a bit confused now.

Comment: @RoyC. Those are also infinitives. Your favorite [grammar](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/6824/16052) probably has a section contrasting bare infinitives and *to*-infinitives.

Comment: Those are infinitive constructions, like relative infinitives (_the man to see, the man to paint it_), subject infinitives (_To escape with his life was his dearest desire_), object infinitives (_He started to light a cigarette_), purpose infinitives (_He stopped to light a cigarette_), etc. All have different grammar rules; some use _to_, some don't. It's more complicated than your grammar book says it is. Get a different grammar book.

Comment: I don't agree. _I can swim in the river_, is syntactically a present tense clause with "can" as the tensed verb. Thus "can" (not "swim") is the matrix verb with the non-finite clause "swim in the river" as a catenative complement.

Comment: If _can_ is present tense, where's the affix? Or is it only present tense by fiat? Modal verbs do not inflect for tense; each has its own refractive index where time is concerned. How about _He can't have been finished by ten, because he was in the parlor until 9_? Are _not have been finished by ten, have been finished by ten, been finished by ten,_ and _finished by ten_ all catenative complements? I'd call them all [verb phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), just like _can't have been finished by ten_ or _can swim in the river_.

Comment: I’m puzzled that anyone should doubt that “can” is a present tense verb. “Can” contrasts with “could” as present tense vs preterite just as “open”, say, contrasts with “opened”. This is perhaps most obvious in reported speech when a present tense verb is backshifted to a preterite after a preterite reporting verb: [1] "They open at six" ~ [2] "I thought they opened at six"; [3]"They can speak French" ~ [4]"I thought they could speak French".  (cont below ...)

Comment: The form “open” can be either a present tense form occurring with a subject other than 3rd person singular, as in [i], or else a plain form occurring mostly in imperatives and infinitivals, but “can” can’t occur in these latter constructions: [5] "Open the door". [6] "You should open the door"; [7] *Can swim by the end of the month (cf. _Be able to swim by the end of the month_); [8] *"You should can swim". “Can” thus occurs in constructions where we have present tense verbs but not in those where we have plain form verbs. It follows that “can” must be a present tense verb, not a plain form.

Comment: Traditionally "can swim" has been taken as a constituent (and commonly called 'the verb'). There was a lot of argument about this in the 70s, and many have come round to the view that the auxiliary verbs are special cases of catenative verbs. There are several tests that can be performed to show that the catenative analysis is preferable to the dependent-auxiliary one. For example, adjuncts can be freely inserted between the auxiliary and the lexical verb: _I can **happily** swim in the river_. Try accounting for adjunct insertion under the dependent-auxiliary analysis!

Comment: The argument must have been elsewhere, since English grammarians call _can swim in the river_ a verb phrase, and call both _can_ and _swim_ verbs. _Swim_ is called the matrix verb in this sentence, since it determines the affordances of the clause; _swim_ is an intransitive movement verb, for instance, so it can't take a complement except for a measure phrase. _Can_ is of course a modal auxiliary verb, and must be first in a verb chain.

Comment: There is no ***THE** Verb*; there are merely various constituents containing verbs. The matrix verb in the main clause is traditionally called the "main verb" in the sentence, but that's vague terminology that grammarians rarely use.

Comment: As I've explained to you, in _I can swim in the river_,  "can" is the tensed verb, more precisely a present tense verb (which I also thought I'd explained). How can "swim", the subordinate clause verb possibly be the matrix verb? That defies logic and common sense. As I said, "can swim" is not 'the verb', not a constituent; the dependent-auxiliary analysis simply doesn't hold water. The analysis of "can" as a special kind of catenative verb makes far more sense; the adjunct tense proves that. Btw, it was you, not me, who said, quote: "...the matrix verb (what you might call the "main verb ..."

Comment: By fiat, one can explain anything. If _can_ is present tense because _could_ is past tense, how does tense account for the difference between _You can swim in the river_ and _You could swim in the river_?  If _must_ is past tense because it is historically derived from the preterite root, why does it only have a present tense reference? Tense is not nearly as important as you appear to think. Sorry about that. BTW, "explaining clearly" is not what's at issue here.

Comment: I did say **'syntactically'** in my first message, and that's what you disputed, I recall. Of course the modals like "can" and "will" etc. are not restricted to present time meanings. For example, _The film will be seen at the Sundance festival_ is syntactically a present tense clause with "will" as the tensed verb. But in that example, "will" clearly expressed reference to future time ---
something that could be done in various other ways as well ("The film
is going to be seen at the Sundance festival," "The film is about to
be seen at the Sundance festival," etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The word swim here is a bare infinitive. [This page](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/infin2.htm) from the website of University College London reads:

Infinitives with to are referred to specifically as TO-INFINITIVES, in order to distinguish them from BARE INFINITIVES, in which to is absent.

To-infinitive: Help me to open the gate

Bare infinitive: Help me open the gate

You can read on the [Kaplan International](http://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/how-to-use-the-infinitive-verb-in-english) website (as well as many other grammar websites and books), that the bare infinitive is used as the main verb (or matrix verb, according to John Lawler's answer) after auxiliary verbs such as 'do', 'should', '**can**', and 'will'.

So now it should be obvious what the roles are:

**can** is an auxiliary verb that qualifies the main verb which is **swim**. Together, they form a simple verb phrase that is used to attribute to the subject of the sentence (in this sentence *I*) the **ability** (~**can**) to do the main action (here the main action is **to swim**).

Comment: Not true! _I can swim in the river_, is syntactically a present tense clause with "can" as the tensed verb. Thus "can" (not "swim") is the matrix verb with the non-finite clause "swim in the river" as a catenative complement.

Comment: Though not everyone believes this is the case.